# Why doesn't TextField grow either statically or dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, miglayout

In the following class a worker is created inside dialog. While worker executing, it updates text filed in dialog.

Unfortunately, the width of TextField does not grow according to content.

Moreover, the text field width is narrow initially, exactly to fit it's content, despite the fact it is configured to grow in `MigLayout`.

How to fix?

```
public abstract class JStatusMessageWorkerDialog<T> extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6373593735878434741L;

    private class Worker extends SwingWorker<T, String> {

        private String statusMessage;

        private Worker() {
        }

        public synchronized String getStatusMessage() {
            return statusMessage;
        }

        public synchronized void setStatusMessage(String newValue) {
            String oldValue = this.statusMessage;
            this.statusMessage = newValue;
            firePropertyChange("statusMessage", oldValue, newValue);
        }

        @Override
        protected T doInBackground() throws Exception {
            return JStatusMessageWorkerDialog.this.doInBackground();
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            JStatusMessageWorkerDialog.this.dispose();
        }



    } // CorpusWorker class

    Worker worker;

    Icon corpusPropgressIcon = createIcon();

    JLabel corpusProgressIconLabel = new JLabel(corpusPropgressIcon);

    JPanel iconPanel = new JPanel();
    {
        iconPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill"));
        iconPanel.add(corpusProgressIconLabel, "");
    }

    JTextField statusText = new JTextField();
    {
        statusText.setEditable(false);
        statusText.setText("text");
    }


    JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
    {
        statusPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill"));
        statusPanel.add(statusText, "growx");
    }

    AbstractAction closeAction = new AbstractAction("Отмена") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            closeAction.setEnabled(false);
            worker.cancel(true);
        }
    };

    JButton closeButton = new JButton(closeAction);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    {
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(closeButton);
    }

    {
        setLayout(new MigLayout("debug, fill"));

        add(iconPanel, "split");
        add(statusPanel, "wrap");
        add(buttonPanel, "w 640px, grow");
    }



    public JStatusMessageWorkerDialog() {

        worker = createWorker();
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if( "statusMessage".equals(evt.getPropertyName()) ) {
                    statusText.setText((String) evt.getNewValue());
                    //statusText.validate();

                    //statusPanel.invalidate();
                    //statusPanel.doLayout();

                    statusText.revalidate();
                }

            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                worker.execute();
            }
        });

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                closeAction.actionPerformed(null);
            }
        });

    }


    protected Worker createWorker() {
        return new Worker();
    }

    protected Icon createIcon() {
        return UIManager.getDefaults().getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
    }

    protected void setStatusMessage(String newValue) {
        worker.setStatusMessage(newValue);
    }

    public String getStatusMessage() {
        return worker.getStatusMessage();
    }

    protected abstract T doInBackground() throws Exception;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JStatusMessageWorkerDialog<Object> dialog = new JStatusMessageWorkerDialog<Object>() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {


                Thread.sleep(5000);

                setStatusMessage("state 2");

                Thread.sleep(5000);

                setStatusMessage("state 3");

                return null;
            }
        };

        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: As a side note, your calls to `setStatusMessage` in the `doInBackground` are ilegal since they end up modifying the GUI from outside the EDT. (propertyChange is executed in the same thread where firePropertyChange is called). You might want to use the `publish` and `process` mechanisms, or call `invokeLater`.

Comment: @DSquare it is apparently said in manual, that property notifications are done on EDT automatically. May be I understood wrong...

Comment: @DSquare yes it is done in `SwingWorker.SwingWorkerPropertyChangeSuppor` class, which automatically post runs to EDT.

Comment: You are right, I didn't know that SwingWorker uses that Swing-variant by default. Still I think publish-process is cleaner for a SwingWorker.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I do not have access to my computer so I will only
write off the top of my head.

First, to change the initial size of the text field, you need to 
add a parameter to the `JTextField` constructor, which is number of
colums. The text field
calculates its initial width according to the number of columns it has:

```
JTextField statusText = new JTextField(10);
```

The combination of `grow` and `fill` constraint makes the component
grow when the window is resized. It does not make it grow when the
content changes -- one has to do it manually.

In my opinion, it is preferable to create a text field big enough to 
containt the largest text, rather than to change it dynamically.